# Download the latest artifact from the last successful pipeline that produced the artifact?

Tags: gitlab

GitLab provides a mechanism to [download a single artifact file from specific tag or branch](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/job_artifacts.html#download-a-single-artifact-file-from-specific-tag-or-branch). The has the very nice feature of,

> Download a single artifact file for a specific job of the **latest successful pipeline** for the given reference name from inside the job’s artifacts archive. The file is extracted from the archive and streamed to the client.

Latest successful pipeline, means if the pipeline failed and no artifacts were produced, you don't get that pipeline.

However, the problem I'm having is that the latest successful pipeline may not produce the artifact I need. The job that produces the artifact runs conditionally based on the contents of the commit. How do I download the last artifact produced by the last successful pipeline that **produced the artifact I need**?